# How to draw images over image and save it as a single image in android

Tags: java, android

Hi guyz i am new to this,

I want to draw an image over image and want to save it as a single image(one image is smaller than other one).
Please tell me how to do this.

I Have tried RelativeLayout to draw an image over image using imagview and able to implement drag and drop for the smaller one. but I am not able to Save them as a single image.
Any Help or Idea would be great????????

Thanks 
Davender

Comment: you have use canvas to do this

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by using canvas.

```
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this
                .getResources(), R.drawable.first);
        /* set other image top of the first icon */
        Bitmap bitmapStar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this
                .getResources(), R.drawable.second);

        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawARGB(0x00, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapStar, 0, 0, null);

        BitmapDrawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bmOverlay);
        dr.setBounds(0, 0, dr.getIntrinsicWidth(), dr.getIntrinsicHeight());

        imageView.setImageDrawable(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [layer-list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) as this seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy: [Draw Image/Text on Image in Android](http://androidclarified.wordpress.com/2018/06/10/writing-text-pasting-image-on-bitmap-image-programatically/)

Read the above article gives good explanation of working on Bitmaps in Android. Basically to write/edit Image in Android you first need to convert it into a mutable Bitmap. Once you have a Bitmap you can easily construct a Canvas from it and then draw anything(text,line,image) on the Canvas. Canvas basically acts as a drawing board.

Below code snippet shows how I draw dino image over an jungle Image using the same canvas concept

```
/* This jungle.png will be used as the canvas to draw an another image over it. Hence we make it mutable using the copy API
as shown below
*/
      Bitmap jungle = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.jungle).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
      // Decoding the dinosaur image resource into a Bitmap
      Bitmap dino= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dino);
      // Here we construct the canvas with the specified bitmap to draw onto
      Canvas canvas=new Canvas(jungle);

/*Here we draw the dinosaur image on the canvas using the drawBitmap API.
drawBitmap takes in four parameters
1 . The Bitmap to draw
2.  X co-ordinate to draw from
3.  Y co ordinate to draw from
4.  Paint object to define style
*/
      canvas.drawBitmap(dino,(jungle.getWidth())/4,250,new Paint());

      imageView.setImageBitmap(jungle);
```